# how to make a given color darker

Tags: actionscript-3

I need to darken a given color by given percentage, if the percentage is 1 the black color should be returned and if the percentage is 0 the originalColor should be returned.

```
private  function getDarkenedColor ( originalColor : uint, darkPercentage : Number = 0.5 ) : uint {

var red : uint = UtilColor.extractColor( originalColor, UtilColor.EXTRACT_COLOR_RED );
var blue : uint = UtilColor.extractColor( originalColor, UtilColor.EXTRACT_COLOR_BLUE );
var green : uint = UtilColor.extractColor( originalColor, UtilColor.EXTRACT_COLOR_GREEN );

return (new ColorTransform()).color; //please complete this line

}
```

Comment: "please complete this line" ... hope nobody will do that for you. Color channels are from 0 to 255. No matter what value they are at you can multiply it by a percentage to darken them, 0% completely dark (0), 100% current value. It's really a very simple math.

Comment: Sounds like Homework to me.

Comment: yes that was simple and nobody completed the line for me and finally I completed it by myself                                            return (new ColorTransform( 1, 1, 1, 1, red  * fadePercentage, green * fadePercentage, blue* fadePercentage)).color;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if the percentage is 1 the black color should be returned and if the percentage is 0 the originalColor should be returned

Then it is a **ratio**, not a percentage

Therefore you just have to multiply each component (red, blue, green) by your given ratio.